# How can messages be appearing on signs if the player didn't place them?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

In my son's Minecraft PE world, random signs keep appearing. One said "angels fear to tread fools rush in" [sic] and the other said "you will dide" [sic]. He found these particular signs underground after following a trail of rare rock. A misquote and a spelling mistake suggest it's someone playing around.  But I know it wasn't him because he was slightly freaked out...

How does this happen? Thanks :)

Here are three screenshots:

[image: Screenshot]
[image: Screenshot]
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Is your son playing on a multiplayer server? Is he using any mods? Is he using a downloaded map? The answer to one of these is yes.

Comment: If he is playing by himself he will have the world all to himself, no talking and nothing else in the logs. Depending how tech savy you are, you may find the logs in `C:\Documents and Settings\Application Data\{His Username Here}\.minecraft\ ` for windows XP (Trust us, it's there.) or `C:\Users\{His Username Here}\Application Data\.minecraft` for Windows 7/Vista/Windows 8. Take note that the logs may be in a logs folder.

Comment: @ColeBusby It's Pocket Edition.

Comment: @Timtech That information was edited after my comment was posted.

Comment: @ColeBusby Same as my answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your son and daughter are playing on a Local Area Network. If your wifi is not password protected, someone could easily log on and edit your world.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding. He plays with my daughter, but it wasn't her, she's only 7 and she's only interested in her sheep etc. I thinks it's the mod or custom map thing.  Thanks for explaining - I don't understand fully but I'm trying lol.  So there's not another person in there with them, or capable of visiting? I've just checked they are on local server multiplayer.

Comment: And I'll look at the logs tomorrow - I'm quite tech savy but not when it comes to minecraft - he's on PE on the iPad though so I'm not sure there will be logs on my computer. God I feel old.

Comment: @Sarahj If you are on a local area network, only people connected to your wireless router can join. He may have set the signs up himself... Having Pocket Edition rules out the mods and custom maps portion. As I stated before, it was probably something he set up himself.

Comment: He didn't set it up on purpose though... He was genuinely freaked out.  Do you mean he set it up without realising?  I'm 100% sure he didn't, he does put codes in or something that generate new worlds.

Comment: I'd have to doubt mods, unless it is a really bad one.  "you will dide" is quite the typo to not get found and fixed really quickly.

Comment: @Sarahj If he has no mods, this was probably something he did. Ask him what seed he used on his world. The seed is the code used to generate random things on the map, like trees, oceans, plants, etc.

Comment: @Batophobia I posted that before I found out it was Minecraft PE.

Comment: I will, I'll ask him about the seed, I think that is the key to the whole thing! Thanks, that's made me realise how little I know and put my mind at rest!  :)

Comment: @Sarahj Seeds won't generate this kind of stuff, unless it's some kind of Easter Egg that was recently added. Let us know what the seed is :) Also, since this helped you, would you mind checking the green checkmark next to my answer? Thanks!

Comment: I will, I wish I understood it because lots of unusual things happen - apparently its rare to see herabrine and he's regularly popping up in their game! My daughter quite likes him, lol they have screen shots and everything. I'll get back to you with the seed tomorrow, thanks again. :)

Comment: @Sarahj Herobrine is **not** in Minecraft Pocket Edition. It's hard to believe what you are talking about, especially since there's no native screenshot-taking ability. Please try not to exaggerate :)

Comment: Worlds are open to network by default, and most homes have unsecured wifi. Probably someone connected to his world. This answer should probably be deleted since it's about the wrong game.

Comment: You can take a shot of any thing on the screen with an iPad, I can post them for you to see! Lol I'm a 40 year old woman, I have no intention of exaggerating - apologies if it looks that way!  And my wifi is definitely secure.

Comment: @Sarahj Sorry, but I'm used to tuning out the Herobrine stuff, as he's never been implemented into any version of Minecraft at any time.

Comment: Since your wifi is secure, I don't know what would be the answer to your question. Definitely ask him about the seed :) Or your daughter - whichever one is hosting the LAN session.

Comment: Happy to share the pics anytime, and I'll get on the seed thing tomorrow.  Thanks again :)

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: No idea on the seed, apparently he just pressed 'new' and it started.  All sorts sprung up today, more signs, a little structure with red stones that are rare that led into a tunnel...diamonds in blocks at the bottom. I might just post the pics on an FB page in case someone recognises it.

Comment: @Sarahj I'd appreciate that. I've never heard of a scenario like this O_o

Comment: @timtech I've just registered on your website & I'll send u the pics there - when an administrator has confirmed my account... Lol

Comment: @Sarahj It's confirmed... it's just that unfortunately I get a lot of bots so I have to confirm accounts first.

Comment: @Sarahj You can edit the question to include the picture. This is ***much*** preferred to moving the discussion to another site, as there's then no way for anyone else to help you here.

Comment: @Sarahj You include the picture without needing to create an account on imgur. On the iPad come to this question then edit the question and press the image button, then upload. Since this is Pocket Edition, I will let you know that I have to agree with SevenSidedDie that It should be a user.

Comment: @dlras2 I've added three screenshots to the question.

Comment: I think your son may be playing a joke on you. Signs are not generated automatically

Comment: He's not playing a joke, because a) he's not that good a liar, and b) I was with him when he saw it and his reactions were genuine. I think I'm going to send these pics and my questions to the app designer.

Comment: Good luck with Mojang. They'll probably tell you the same thing as you heard here though.

Comment: I sense doubt lol....we'll see